# Plotly: How to round display text in annotated heatmap but keep full format on hover?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am drawing a correlation matrix of the Titanic dataset.

```
df_corr = df.corr()
```

Originally, the matrix looks like this:

```
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
            z=df_corr.to_numpy(),
            x=df_corr.columns.tolist(),
            y=df_corr.index.tolist(),
            zmax=1, zmin=-1,
            showscale=True,
            hoverongaps=True
            )
# add title
fig.update_layout(title_text='<i><b>Correlation not round</b></i>')
```

[image: not_round]

I want to round the float number, so they display less digits after the `.` dot.

The current workaround is actually round the pandas dataframe before input.

```
df_corr_round = df_corr.round(3)
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
            z=df_corr_round.to_numpy(),
            x=df_corr.columns.tolist(),
            y=df_corr.index.tolist(),
            zmax=1, zmin=-1,
            showscale=True,
            hoverongaps=True
            )
# add title
fig.update_layout(title_text='<i><b>Correlation round</b></i>')
```

[image: round]

But the workaround also rounds the text when I hover mouse over. I want hover text in full detail while display text are round.

Can I display less digits on each cell without changing the input dataframe ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can only assume that you're building your `ff.create_annotated_heatmap()` from a list of lists as they do in the docs under [Annotated Heatmaps in Python](https://plotly.com/python/annotated-heatmap/). And don't worry if you're using a pandas dataframe instead. The complete snippet below will show you how you construct a [correlation matrix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) from a pandas dataframe with multiple timeseries of stocks `px.data.stocks`, and then make a list of lists using `df.values.tolist()` to build an annotated heatmap. If you're doing something similar, then one way of building the annotations would be to define a text like this:

```
z_text = [[str(y) for y in x] for x in z]
```

And then all you'll need to get the number of digits you want is use [round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

```
z_text = [[str(round(y, 1)) for y in x] for x in z]
```

As you can see below, this approach (1) does *not* alter the source dataframe like `df_corr.round()` would have, (2) shows only 1 digit in the figure, and (3) shows a longer number format on hover. In the image I'm hovering on `MSFT / FB = 0.5`

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import pandas as pd

df = px.data.stocks()#.tail(50)
df = df.drop(['date'], axis = 1)
dfc = df.corr()
z = dfc.values.tolist()

# change each element of z to type string for annotations
# z_text = [[str(y) for y in x] for x in z]
z_text = [[str(round(y, 1)) for y in x] for x in z]

# set up figure 
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z, x=list(df.columns),
                                     y=list(df.columns),
                                     annotation_text=z_text, colorscale='agsunset')

# add title
fig.update_layout(title_text='<i><b>Confusion matrix</b></i>',
                  #xaxis = dict(title='x'),
                  #yaxis = dict(title='x')
                 )

# add custom xaxis title
fig.add_annotation(dict(font=dict(color="black",size=14),
                        x=0.5,
                        y=-0.15,
                        showarrow=False,
                        text="",
                        xref="paper",
                        yref="paper"))

# add custom yaxis title
fig.add_annotation(dict(font=dict(color="black",size=14),
                        x=-0.35,
                        y=0.5,
                        showarrow=False,
                        text="",
                        textangle=-90,
                        xref="paper",
                        yref="paper"))

# adjust margins to make room for yaxis title
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=50, l=200))

# add colorbar
fig['data'][0]['showscale'] = True
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the data at hand, so I haven't been able to check the execution, but I think the following code will work. Please refer to the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/annotated-heatmap/).

```
df_corr_round = df_corr.round(3)
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
            z=df_corr,
            x=df_corr.columns.tolist(),
            y=df_corr.index.tolist(),
            zmax=1, zmin=-1,
            showscale=True,
            hoverongaps=True,
            annotation_text=df_corr_round.to_numpy(),
            )
# add title
fig.update_layout(title_text='<i><b>Correlation round</b></i>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Set **texttemplate** and **hovertemplate** using **update_traces**. Also need to declare **text_auto=True**

```
fig = px.imshow(
    matrix,  
    text_auto=True, 
    aspect="auto", 
    color_continuous_scale='Viridis'


fig.update_traces(
    texttemplate='%{z:.2f}',
    hovertemplate=("%{x}<br>%{y}<br><b>correlation: %{z}</b><extra></extra>")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `".round()"` method. You can do the same manipulations with dataframes.

The following code is for values with non-rounded matrix values with the plotly.express:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

fig = px.imshow(
    np.random.rand(4, 4),
    text_auto=True
)
fig.show()
```

[The graph with non-rounded values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI2lw.png)

And now with rounded:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

fig = px.imshow(
    np.random.rand(4, 4).round(2),
    text_auto=True
)
fig.show()
```

[With rounded values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl4yv.png)