# Correlation Heatmap in Plotly

Tags: python, plot, plotly, seaborn, heatmap

I have created a lower triangular correlation heatmap using Seaborn that I loved. Now trying to create the same using Plotly. Unfortunately, not being able to fine tune it like I did with Seaborn.

```
names = ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
r = pd.DataFrame(index = names, columns = names)
r['U'] = np.array([1.0,   0.53,    0.26,  0.63, 0.52, 0.65] )
r['V'] = np.array([0.53,   1.0,   -0.17, 0.83, 1, 0.85])
r['W'] = np.array([0.26,  -0.17,    1.0,  0.04, -0.15, 0.09])
r['X'] = np.array([0.63, 0.83, 0.04, 1, 0.83, 0.80])
r['Y'] = np.array([0.52, 1, -0.15, 0.83, 1, 0.86])
r['Z'] = np.array([0.65, 0.85, 0.09, 0.80, 0.86, 1.0])

print(r)
```

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns

# sns.set_theme(style="white")

mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(r, dtype=bool))

# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))

# Generate a custom diverging colormap
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(230, 20, n=256, as_cmap=True)

# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
sns.heatmap(r, 
            mask=mask, 
            cmap=cmap, 
            vmax=1, 
            vmin = -.25,
            center=0,
            square=True, 
            linewidths=.5,
            annot = True,
            fmt='.2f', 
            annot_kws={'size': 10},
            cbar_kws={"shrink": .75})

plt.title('Asset Correlation Matrix')
plt.tight_layout()
ax.tick_params(axis = 'x', labelsize = 8)
ax.set_ylim(len(corr)+1, -1)
# plt.savefig('corrTax.png', dpi = 600)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I am trying to create this using Plotly. Here is what I have able to do so far.

```
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(r, dtype=bool))
rLT = r.mask(mask)

heat = go.Heatmap(
    z = rLT,
    x = rLT.columns.values,
    y = rLT.columns.values,
    zmin = - 0.25, # Sets the lower bound of the color domain
    zmax = 1,
    xgap = 1, # Sets the horizontal gap (in pixels) between bricks
    ygap = 1,
    colorscale = 'RdBu'
)

title = 'Asset Correlation Matrix'

layout = go.Layout(
    title_text=title, 
    title_x=0.5, 
    width=600, 
    height=600,
    xaxis_showgrid=False,
    yaxis_showgrid=False,
    yaxis_autorange='reversed'
)

fig=go.Figure(data=[heat], layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

[image]

- Seaborn colormap that I was create, I want to create something similar in Plotly. How can I do that?
- I was able to control the axis label sizes.
- Would love to put values into each box (`annot` option in seaborn), with rounding option

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way I've found to remove top triangle in view

```
# Correlation
df_corr = data.corr().round(1)  
# Mask to matrix
mask = np.zeros_like(df_corr, dtype=bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
# Viz
df_corr_viz = df_corr.mask(mask).dropna(how='all').dropna('columns', how='all')
fig = px.imshow(df_corr_viz, text_auto=True)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I had to add `axis=columns` to the second `dropna()`, and I'd also recommend `.update_xaxes(showgrid=False).update_yaxes(showgrid=False)`.

Answer (score 2):

Deb.
Here it goes the answer for the first of your questions.

> Seaborn colormap that I was create, I want to create something similar in Plotly. How can I do that?

You can use of the built-in [colorscales in Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/builtin-colorscales/), which can be set via the parameter `colorscale` in the Heatmap constructor. Also, you can set Plotly's theme to get rid of the ugly background

```py
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

pio.templates.default = "plotly_white"

go.Heatmap(
    z=corr.mask(mask),
    x=corr.columns,
    y=corr.columns,
    colorscale=px.colors.diverging.RdBu,
    zmin=-1,
    zmax=1
)
```

[image: Example on a dummy dataset]

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to put the numbers inside boxes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use plotly function `create_annotated_heatmap` from `plotly.figure_factory` instead of the normal plotly heatmap. This function accepts numpy array instead of the dataframe directly. [Official Reference](https://plotly.com/python/annotated-heatmap)
Here is my solution

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

corr = df.iloc.corr()
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr, dtype=bool))
df_mask = corr.mask(mask)

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z=df_mask.to_numpy(), 
                                  x=df_mask.columns.tolist(),
                                  y=df_mask.columns.tolist(),
                                  colorscale=px.colors.diverging.RdBu,
                                  hoverinfo="none", #Shows hoverinfo for null values
                                  showscale=True, ygap=1, xgap=1
                                 )

fig.update_xaxes(side="bottom")

fig.update_layout(
    title_text='Heatmap', 
    title_x=0.5, 
    width=1000, 
    height=1000,
    xaxis_showgrid=False,
    yaxis_showgrid=False,
    xaxis_zeroline=False,
    yaxis_zeroline=False,
    yaxis_autorange='reversed',
    template='plotly_white'
)

# NaN values are not handled automatically and are displayed in the figure
# So we need to get rid of the text manually
for i in range(len(fig.layout.annotations)):
    if fig.layout.annotations[i].text == 'nan':
        fig.layout.annotations[i].text = ""

fig.show()
```

[image]

You can use `zmin` and `zmax` as speciifed by @ottovon

Basic heatmap can also be used but annotations need to be done manually by specifying some function, I presume.

For rounding up annotation refer to this [Plotly: How to round display text in annotated heatmap but keep full format on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65881498/12135727) thread.

Also, you can refer the [Official Docs](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-tickfont) for the sizing of the xticks and the same can be done for yticks. I have not practically implemented them but they should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = **some kinda of pandas data frame**


px.imshow(df.corr())
```